# Android - Loading JSON to ListView

Tags: java, android, json

I'm still pretty new to Android development, am doing an app/project which involves loading this JSON (listed below) into a `ListView` with the name, description, and image, but it has been coming up blank on the emulator. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong - any help would be greatly appreciated! (The more specific the better as I am such a newbie..)

**JSON:**

```
 {
   "success":true,
   "games":[
      {
         "id":"1",
         "name":"Name of the Game",
         "description":"This is what it is about",
         "image":"IMAGE URL"
      }
   ]
}
```

**AndroidJSONParsingActivity:**

```
// URL to make request
    private static final String url = "URL of API";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_GAMES = "games";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    private static final String TAG_IMAGE = "image";

    // games JSONArray
    JSONArray games = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Hash map for ListView
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> gameList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            // Creating JSON Parser instance
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

            try {
                // Getting Array of Games
                games = json.getJSONArray(TAG_GAMES);

                // looping through All Games
                for(int i = 0; i < games.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = games.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each JSON item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String image = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);

                    // is again JSON Object
                    JSONObject author = c.getJSONObject(TAG_DESCRIPTION);
                    String name = author.getString(TAG_NAME);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put( TAG_IMAGE, image);
                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    gameList.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, gameList,
                    R.layout.list_item,
                    new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_DESCRIPTION }, new int[] {
                            R.id.name, R.id.description });

            setListAdapter(adapter);

            // selecting single ListView item
            ListView lv = getListView();

            // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // getting values from selected ListItem
                    String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
                    String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description)).getText().toString();

                    // Starting new intent
                    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description);
                    startActivity(in);

                }
            });



        }
```

**JSON Parser:**

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

**main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- Main ListView 
         Always give id value as list(@android:id/list)
    -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

list_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- Name Label -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#43bd00"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#acacac"
            android:paddingBottom="2dip" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Adding LogCat info:

```
01-03 06:16:15.254: E/ActivityThread(616): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d47b40 that was originally bound here
01-03 06:16:15.254: E/ActivityThread(616): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d47b40 that was originally bound here
01-03 06:16:15.254: E/ActivityThread(616):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
01-03 06:16:15.254: E/ActivityThread(616):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
01-03 06:16:15.254: E/ActivityThread(616):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
01-03 06:16:15.254: E/ActivityThread(616):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
01-03 06:16:15.254: E/ActivityThread(616):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
01-03 06:16:15.254: E/ActivityThread(616):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
01-03 06:16:15.254: E/ActivityThread(616):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
01-03 06:16:15.254: E/ActivityThread(616):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
01-03 06:16:15.254: E/ActivityThread(616):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
01-03 06:16:15.254: E/ActivityThread(616):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
01-03 06:16:15.254: E/ActivityThread(616):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
01-03 06:16:15.254: E/ActivityThread(616):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-03 06:16:15.254: E/ActivityThread(616):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
01-03 06:16:15.254: E/ActivityThread(616):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
01-03 06:16:15.254: E/ActivityThread(616):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
01-03 06:16:15.254: E/ActivityThread(616):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-03 06:16:15.365: E/StrictMode(616): null
01-03 06:16:15.365: E/StrictMode(616): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d47b40 that was originally bound here
01-03 06:16:15.365: E/StrictMode(616):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
01-03 06:16:15.365: E/StrictMode(616):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
01-03 06:16:15.365: E/StrictMode(616):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
01-03 06:16:15.365: E/StrictMode(616):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
01-03 06:16:15.365: E/StrictMode(616):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
01-03 06:16:15.365: E/StrictMode(616):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
01-03 06:16:15.365: E/StrictMode(616):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
01-03 06:16:15.365: E/StrictMode(616):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
01-03 06:16:15.365: E/StrictMode(616):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
01-03 06:16:15.365: E/StrictMode(616):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
01-03 06:16:15.365: E/StrictMode(616):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
01-03 06:16:15.365: E/StrictMode(616):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
```

Comment: Every thing will be ok but toy must use Asynctask() for getting Json Response

Comment: Before the post was edited, a comma was missing from the JSON snippet. Was that a copy/paste error? If not, your JSON is not properly formatted.

Comment: Hi tiffon, the JSON is properly formatted- that was just my copy/paste error!

Comment: @JaneWilliams : first make sure you are getting value in `gameList` . if only images is not appearing then you can not directly set web url to ImangeView. for setting weburl to imageview you will need to first download it then use it as imageview src .

Answer (score 1):

**AsyncTask.class**

```
class LoadMovies extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Category>>{

private YourActivity activity;

public LoadMovies(YourActivity activty){
    activity = activty;
}

        private final static String TAG = "Log";


        @Override
        protected List<Category> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            InputStream ips = null;
            JSONObject json = null;

            try{
                DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(new HttpGet("http://youtsite"));

                ips = response.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ips));
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while((line = buffer.readLine()) != null){
                    builder.append(line+"\n");
                }
                json = new JSONObject(builder.toString());

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Log.i(TAG, e.toString());
            }

                List<Category> list = new ArrayList<Category>();
                JSONArray array = json.optJSONObject("data").optJSONArray("reviews");
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject rss = array.optJSONObject(i); 
                                    Category cat = new Category();
                                    cat.addName(rss.optString("name"));  
                                    cat.addCode(rss.optString("code"));                     
                    list.add(cat);
                }

            return list;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(List<Category> result){
            super.onPostExecute(result);
                    Youractivity.mMoviesAdapter.addCategory(result);
        }

    }
```

**Category.class**

```
public class Category {
    private String name;
    private String code;

    void addName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    void addCode(String code){
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getName(){
     return this.name;
    }

    String getCode(){
        return this.code;
    }
}
```

Adapter.class

```
class MoviesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Category> {

    Context c;      
    List<Category> mListCategory; 

    public MoviesAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResource, List<Categoryy> list) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResource, list);
        c = context;

        mListCategory= list;
    }

    public void addCategory(List<MoviesCategory> list){
        mListCategory.addAll(list);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View v = convertView;
        if(v == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourview, null);
        }

        TextView title =  (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView code=  (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.code);

        Category cat = getItem(position);
        if(mov != null){
            title.setText(cat.getName());
            code.setText(cat.getCode());

        }

        return v;
    }   

}
```

And in MainActivity call all

```
    public class YourActivity extends MainActivity{
    private ListView mCategory;
    private List<Category> mCategoryArray = new ArrayList<Category>();
    private LoadMovies mLoadMovies;
    public mMoviesAdapter adapter;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
   super.onCreate(bundle);

    //MoviesList        
        mMoviesAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(this, R.layout.main_movies_adapter, R.id.youradapterlayout, mCategoryArray );
        mCategoryList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.movies_adapter_list);
        mMoviesList.setAdapter(mMoviesAdapter);

        mLoadMovies = new LoadMovies(this);
        mLoadMovies.execute();
}
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, ozik. I'm sorry to be a bother, but I'm having some issues incorporating your code with mine.. do you have any advice? (such as, what type of adapter to use, or where to place variables..)

Comment: Wait just minute i help you! )

Answer (score 1):

this is my code

```
public class as extends AsyncTask   {

            public as(int aa)       {
                        }

            @Override       protected Object doInBackground(Object... params)       {           //int price1,sp1,save1;             try             {           JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://192.168.1.97/inventory/Client.php?action=productlist&page_no="+aa+"&user_id="+userid+"");            Log.e("url", String.valueOf("http://192.168.1.97/inventory/Client.php?action=productlist&page_no="+aa+"&user_id="+userid+""));          mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                try{
                    JSONArray  products = json.getJSONArray("product");
                    Log.v("inside", "inside");

                    Log.e("pages",String.valueOf( json.get("products_count")));
                    pagecount=json.getInt("page_count");

                    //JSONObject e1 = pages.getJSONObject("tot_pages");

                //  Log.e("totpages",e1.getString("tot_pages"));
                //  pagecount=json.getInt("tot_pages");
                    // pcount=json.getInt("p_count");


                    for(int i=0;i<products.length();i++){   
                        String img,img1;
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
                        Log.e("p c",String.valueOf(i));
                        JSONObject e = products.getJSONObject(i);
                        Log.v("name", String.valueOf(e.getString("name")));
                        map.put("name",e.getString("name"));
                        map.put("price",e.getString("price"));
                        map.put("sp",e.getString("special_price"));
                        map.put("image", String.valueOf(e.getString("image")));
                    float price1 = Float.parseFloat(e.getString("price"));
                    float sp1=Float.parseFloat(e.getString("special_price"));
                    float save1=price1-sp1;
                    map.put("save",String.valueOf(save1));


                        mylist.add(map);    

                    }       
                }catch(JSONException e)
                {
                     Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());

                }



                    }   catch(Exception e)
             {      e.printStackTrace();





             }
                            return null;




                        }

            @Override       protected void onPostExecute(Object result)         {           //lv.setAdapter(new ItemListBaseAdapter(AllItems.this, mylist));
                        }




            @Override       protected void onPreExecute()       {           try{            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(AllItems.this, "", "Please wait");             }           catch (Exception e) {


                    e.printStackTrace();

                                }           super.onPreExecute();       }

        }       //previous check method


                public class ItemListBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

                    private  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> itemDetailsrrayList;         Bitmap bitmap[];           Context context1;           String ab;



                        private LayoutInflater l_Inflater;

            public ItemListBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist)      {
                            itemDetailsrrayList = mylist;           //l_Inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);            context1=context;
                }

            public int getCount() {             return itemDetailsrrayList.size();
                        }

            public Object getItem(int position) {           return itemDetailsrrayList.get(position);       }

            public long getItemId(int position) {
                            return position;        }



                    public View getView( final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)        {
              int ruban=3;
                        //final ViewHolder holder;

                        if (convertView == null) {
                    l_Inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context1);

                     convertView = l_Inflater.inflate(R.layout.list1, null,true);



                                }

                            TextView txt_itemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);            TextView txt_itemDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mrp1);          TextView txt_itemPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ourprice1);           TextView txt_itemSave = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.save1);            //holder.txt_itemw = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);           WebView itemimmm=(WebView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);            TextView t1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.t1);             TextView t2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.t2);             TextView t3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.t3);             ImageView addprod=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.addprod);            final Button decprod=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.decprod);
                final TextView disprod=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.disprod);            decprod.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);          disprod.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            txt_itemDescription.setPaintFlags(txt_itemDescription.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);           itemimmm.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
                            txt_itemName.setTypeface(AllItems.face);            txt_itemDescription.setTypeface(AllItems.face);             txt_itemPrice.setTypeface(AllItems.face);           txt_itemSave.setTypeface(AllItems.face);            //holder.txt_itemw.setTypeface(AllItems.face);          t1.setTypeface(AllItems.rupee);
                t2.setTypeface(AllItems.rupee);
                t3.setTypeface(AllItems.rupee);
                //StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                //StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);           txt_itemName.setText(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).get("name"));            txt_itemDescription.setText(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).get("price"));            txt_itemPrice.setText(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).get("sp"));
                txt_itemSave.setText(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).get("save"));            //holder.txt_itemw.setText(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).get("type"));
                itemimmm.loadUrl(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).get("image"));           if(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).get("name").equals("Daughter")||itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).get("name").equals("Ethnic"))            {
                Log.e("name", String.valueOf(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).get("name")));           //decprod.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);          //disprod.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);          }

                  // Log.e("before", "try");

                        /*  try{

                        Log.e("try", String.valueOf(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).get("image")));
                     Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).get("image")).getContent());
                     itemimmm.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
                    }catch(Exception ex){

                         ex.printStackTrace();
                         Log.e("error",String.valueOf(ex));
                     itemimmm.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier("ic_launcher", "drawable", getPackageName())); 

                        Log.e("catch", "catch");*/

                //prodImage.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier("sample", "drawable", getPackageName()));


                //itemimmm.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier("ic_launcher", "drawable", getPackageName())); 



                    //holder.itemImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap[position]);

                              addprod.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0)          {


                       //decprod.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        //disprod.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



                                       /*   int k = 0;
                                        if(disprod.getText()!="" || disprod.getText()!=null){
                                            k = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(disprod.getText()));
                                        }
                                        disprod.setText(String.valueOf(++k));
                                        disprod.setTag(k);*/
                                       Log.v("position", String.valueOf(position));


                                new AddCart(decprod,disprod).execute();




                    }           });   




                decprod.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0)
                    {
                        //Log.v("item name", String.valueOf(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).get("price")));

                    }           });




               /* textView.setText(getelement()[position]);

                 ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.icon);
                 imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);*/




                    return convertView;




                   }
```

Comment: thank you for the code - what do you think would be the best way to incorporate async into mine?  (Sorry to be so inexperienced, i really do appreciate your help!)